# Duplicate SQL Server database on same server cannot be accessed

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, dsn

I am using SQL Server Workgroup Edition on Windows Server 2003 R2

My classic ASP pages access my production database using a system DSN. All working here.

Code like this...

```
<%
dbName= "ProdDB"  
userID = "PublicUser"  
pwd = "PublicUserPW"

Set objConn = Server.createObject("ADODB.Connection")  
objConn.connectionString = "DSN=MySystemDSN"  
objConn.open dbName, userID, pwd  
%>
```

For development and testing, I created a copy of ProdDB in Enterprise Manager by

- Backing up ProdDB
- Restoring from the ProdDB backup set to a new database called TestDB

My understanding was that the restored database would contain an exact copy of the data as well as users, roles etc. Comparing both databases in Enterprise Manager seemed to back up this assumption.

So... I assumed I can access the test copy using the same credentials and only change the dbName, like so...

```
<%
dbName= "TestDB"  
userID = "PublicUser"  
pwd = "PublicUserPW"

Set objConn = Server.createObject("ADODB.Connection")  
objConn.connectionString = "DSN=MySystemDSN"  
objConn.open dbName, userID, pwd  
%>
```

However, now my page returns

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
>   source name not found and no default
>   driver specified

I have even tried creating a new System DSN, with a default database pointing at TestDB. Still no joy.

I'm sure I'm doing something simple and silly. Any assistance gratefully received.

Comment: Looks like it's not finding a system dsn called "MySystemDsn".  Open the ODBC manager, under administrative tools.  Check the tab labeled "System DSN".

Comment: No, definitely not that. The pages accessing the ProdDB database are working fine, and they use the same DSN.

Comment: The only thing that has changed in the code is the dbName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [open method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms808201) says it's declared:

```
connection.Open ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
```

So it looks like you're passing in `TestDB` as the connection string.  I usually call open without specifying any arguments.  Grab a connection string from [connectionstrings dot com](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005), and:

```
objConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=testdb;" & _
    "User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
objConn.Open
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar, you may be on to something here. It turns out there is another system DSN with the same name as the Prod DB, so the connection was probably working via that DSN (i.e. the one called ProdDB) rather than the one I thought was being used (i.e. was not using MySystemDSN at all)